# react final form add extra fields as props

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

Hello I have two forms that are different by only one field. So I am thinking of create a common form component and pass only the extra field as an optional property.

Common form:

```
import { Form as ReactFinalForm, Field } from "react-final-form";
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

interface CommonFormProps {
    onSubmit: (values: any) => void;
    extraFields?: typeof Field[];
}

export default function CommonForm(props: CommonFormProps) {
    return (
          <ReactFinalForm
            onSubmit={values => {
              props.onSubmit(values);
            }}
            render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values}) => (
              <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                   // other fields
                 {props.extraFields}
              </Form>
            )}
          />
    );
}
```

Form that needs extra field

```
export default function FormB() {
    return (
        <CommonForm
          extraFields={<Field name="price" validate={required} >
                         {({ input, meta }) => (
              <Form.Group as={Form.Row} controlId="price">
                <Form.Label column sm={4}>
                    Price
                </Form.Label>
                <Col sm={8}>
                  <Form.Control type="text" {...input} />
                </Col>
              </Form.Group>
            )}
          </Field>}
      />
);
}
```

I have tried to define extraFields as typeof Field[] or typeof Field. It makes no difference and error is always

> Type 'Element' is not assignable to type '<FieldValue = any, RP
> extends FieldRenderProps<FieldValue, T> = FieldRenderProps<FieldValue,
> HTMLElement>, T extends HTMLElement = HTMLElement>(props:
> FieldProps<...>) => ReactElement<...>'.   Type 'Element' provides no
> match for the signature '<FieldValue = any, RP extends
> FieldRenderProps<FieldValue, T> = FieldRenderProps<FieldValue,
> HTMLElement>, T extends HTMLElement = HTMLElement>(props:
> FieldProps<...>): ReactElement<...>'.ts(2322) index.tsx(16, 5): The
> expected type comes fro

Could anybody help get rid of this please?

Answer (score 0):

Pass as a child, not a prop:

```
export default function FormB() {
    return (
        <CommonForm>
          <Field name="price" validate={required} >
                         {({ input, meta }) => (
              <Form.Group as={Form.Row} controlId="price">
                <Form.Label column sm={4}>
                    Price
                </Form.Label>
                <Col sm={8}>
                  <Form.Control type="text" {...input} />
                </Col>
              </Form.Group>
            )}
          </Field>}
      </CommonForm>);
}
```

Then use children

```
export default function CommonForm(props: CommonFormProps) {
    return (
          <ReactFinalForm
            onSubmit={values => {
              props.onSubmit(values);
            }}
            render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values}) => (
              <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                   // other fields
                 {props.children}
              </Form>
            )}
          />
    );
}
```

children can be empty